# Can election votes be changed?

Tags: support, election

Once a vote is cast in the election, can it be changed?  When voting for a question/answer, you get time in which you can change your mind, even if the post hasn't been edited.

Are election votes like this?  Can I vote today, change my mind during the week and change my vote?  Or once I push the vote button, is that it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the final phase of the election, [you can change your mind at any time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112852/reordering-votes-in-final-election-phase/112853#112853), with one exception: if you have cast a vote, you can't go back to an empty ballot. In other words, you need to make up your mind whether to participate, but if you participate, you can pick different candidates at the last minute.

For future reference, in the primary phase (which only happens when there are more than 10 candidates), you have [3 hours until your vote is locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/i-cant-undo-or-change-my-vote-in-the-primary-election-phase/76556#76556).

By the way, for questions and answers, you only have 5 minutes to change your vote. If a post has been edited since you voted on it, you can change your vote.